# how to make a scroll looping through a list in a windows phone app?

Tags: scroll, windows-phone

I want to loop Items in a list when scrolling so that will give the feeling of infinite scrolling.
In another way I mean I want if I reach the last Item of a list by scrolling down, the first Item will be under the last one so that the scrolling be like infinite.. any solutions ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like a request to have someone write the code for you.

Comment: Martin, actually I'm asking if it is even possible to do that, and if so, is it just an attribute set to "true" or a hole code behind. I tried to find such an attribute in ListView, ListBox and LongListSelector but couldn't find any related thing.

Comment: Almost anything is possible, but probably requires a lot of custom code to move items from start to end of the list to keep the scrolling working the way you are asking for.